# Why are there "Jedi" and "Sith" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Is there a reason such specific tags in existence? I don't think anyone would try to check "Jedi" and "Sith" tags over "star-wars"..

Comment: Does Sci-Fi do regular tag maintenance?  Could be suggested during that, if there's evidence provided that these tags are indeed not all that useful.

Comment: Jedi and Sith seem like odd examples to pick out, considering we have a [tag:brain] tag.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Jedi and Sith could be combined into Star Wars, while brain isn't a subcategory of one mythos. However, it seems to me there are a fair number of questions about Jedi and Sith, and many many more about Star Wars, so I can see Jedi and Sith being useful, especially if I had a question about one, and wanted to look for an already-asked version of my question before writing it up.

Comment: @Dronz Brain is a subset of [tag:biology], though

Answer (score 11):

While I generally dislike over-normalization, or over-tagging, there are valid uses of the tags.

Currently [jedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi) has 80 questions tagged. [sith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sith) has 40. Granted, many of those questions can probably do without some of the Jedi/Sith tags they have.

The tags *should* be used to help specify or categorize the question. A question about the [titles and ranks within the Jedi Order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71422/5184) makes sense to be tagged with "Jedi". A question about [a doctrine specific to the Sith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7635/5184) makes sense to be tagged with "Sith".

Will anyone try to check "Jedi" or "Sith" over "Star Wars"? No, probably not. The same case could probably be made for a lot of tags which might be grouped within hierarchical tags (which we'll likely never get).

Comment: For few questions (which can be counted on fingers), I don't think tags are necessary unless its for a franchise.

Comment: I used "Sith" tag in searching. Don't tell me the odds!

Comment: Note that tags help add material into the 'related' questions on the sidebar.  Tagging jedi or sith can help provide better quality related questions rather than just star-wars alone.  (Consider how poor the 'related' are on Stack Overflow when someone has a question tagged just 'java' compared to 'java' + 'for-loop' + 'algorithm-analysis')